# Does the inverse of gravity exists?

Tags: gravity

I am not talking about an antigravity effect that would cancel gravity, rather if there is a repulsive force, like when you use two magnets and flip one of them, where it becomes obvious that one is pushing away the other.

Hope the question is a good fit for the site, feel free to migrate it otherwise.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question on [physics.stackexchange.com](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/why-is-gravitation-force-always-attractive)

Comment: Are you asking about Dark Energy (the force that appears to be accelerating the expansion of the universe)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

No such effect has been discovered. Gravity seems to be always attractive, never repulsive. Nor has a particle with negative mass ever been discovered. In particular, antimatter appears to have positive mass.

It is not theoretically impossible, but a particle with negative mass would be very odd, as the faster it moved, the less momentum and energy it would have.

Comment: Note that the reversed energy<--> speed thing is part of tachyon lore, tho' I do not know how putative tachyons are supposed to respond to gravity

Comment: Does anything move, i.e. mass has velocity? If gravity is due to spacetime warp, not attraction, the warp caused density or less dense distribution of matter, there is no speed for matter doesn't move since in quantum the same particle appears over all the places... my hypothetical imagination only :).

Comment: @Mishu米殊 [Spacetime tells matter how to move; matter tells spacetime how to curve](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_Archibald_Wheeler).